# I want to know about the story about Qiyamat, The Dayvof Judgement I Listen when I was young

Tags: prophet-muhammad, islamic-philosophy, prophets, day-of-judgement

I don't remember Many things. But form what I remember is During the day of judgement A Lot of prophet are worrying about their own problem when the human or a group of human IDK ask them about like To beg Allah to forgive our sin.
I don't remember The while story anymore .

Another one is Prophet Muhammad S.A.W Crying and Making Dua for Us his Followers to Forgive us and Grant us the entry To Jannah
I don't remember the whole story
Forgive me If there is any wrong
Can any one of u please tell me

Answer (score 2):

> We were in the company of the Prophet (ﷺ) at a banquet and a cooked
> (mutton) forearm was set before him, and he used to like it. He ate a
> morsel of it and said, "I will be the chief of all the people on the
> Day of Resurrection. Do you know how Allah will gather all the first
> and the last (people) in one level place where an observer will be
> able to see (all) of them and they will be able to hear the announcer,
> and the sun will come near to them. Some People will say: Don't you
> see, in what condition you are and the state to which you have
> reached? Why don't you look for a person who can intercede for you
> with your Lord? Some people will say: Appeal to your father, Adam.'
> They will go to him and say: 'O Adam! You are the father of all
> mankind, and Allah created you with His Own Hands, and ordered the
> angels to prostrate for you, and made you live in Paradise. Will you
> not intercede for us with your Lord? Don't you see in what (miserable)
> state we are, and to what condition we have reached?' On that Adam
> will reply, 'My Lord is so angry as He has never been before and will
> never be in the future; (besides), He forbade me (to eat from) the
> tree, but I disobeyed (Him), (I am worried about) myself! Myself! Go
> to somebody else; go to Noah.' They will go to Noah and say; 'O Noah!
> You are the first amongst the messengers of Allah to the people of the
> earth, and Allah named you a thankful slave. Don't you see in what a
> (miserable) state we are and to what condition we have reached? Will
> you not intercede for us with your Lord? Noah will reply: 'Today my
> Lord has become so angry as he had never been before and will never be
> in the future Myself! Myself! Go to the Prophet (Muhammad). The people
> will come to me, and I will prostrate myself underneath Allah's
> Throne. Then I will be addressed: 'O Muhammad! Raise your head;
> intercede, for your intercession will be accepted, and ask (for
> anything). for you will be given. "
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3340

> Verily the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) recited the words of Allah, the
> Great and Glorious, that Ibrahim uttered. My Lord! lo! they have led
> many of mankind astray:" But whoso followeth me, he verily is of me"
> (al-Qur'an, xiv. 35) and Jesus (peace be upon him) said:" If thou
> punisheth them, lo! they are Thy slaves, and if Thou forgiveth
> them-verily Thou art the Mighty, the Wise" (al-Qur'an, v 117). Then he
> raised his hands and said: O Lord, my Ummah, my Ummah, and wept; so
> Allah the High and the Exalted said: O Gabriel, go to Muhammad (though
> your Lord knows it fully well) and ask him: What makes thee weep? So
> Gabriel (peace be upon him) came to him and asked him, and the
> Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) informed him what he had said (though Allah
> knew it fully well). Upon this Allah said: O Gabriel, go to Muhammad
> and say: Verily We will please thee with regard to your Ummah and
> would not displease thee.
>
> https://sunnah.com/muslim:202

Comment: Thank You soo much brother.